# graphs of polynomial equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Whenever the $x$-axis is a tangent to the graph of an equation, why is the root repeated at that point on the graph?
If we consider the graph of the equation $x^2=0$ and $x^3=0$ the x-axis is tangent to the graph at $(0,0)$, is there a way to determine the multiplicity of the root using the graph?

Comment: Note that if graph is parallel to X axis it implies nothing (E.g. $P(x)=3$) but multiple roots imply that graph is parallel to X-axis.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty I think you mean a part of the graph is parallel to the x axis as in case of x3=0 the point (0,0)

Comment: No, if you look at $x^3$ on every interval (a,b) it is strictly increasing.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty yes I agree but the whole graph is not parallel to x axis?

Comment: What do you mean? an interval is a subset of real line and X-axis is subset of real 2-D plane. Parallelity is not defined between them.

Comment: Ok now I understood it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if all derivatives up to the $n$th derivative is zero the it has $n-1$ zeroes at that point. In other words you will have to draw its derivatives too in order to find multiplicity.

Or you can study concavity but that may not always help as it is hard to differentiate between $x^2$ and $x^4$ from their graphs.

Comment: But why is the root repeated when the x axis is tangent to a point on the graph?

Comment: @PeaceSeeker If $P(x)=Q(x)(x-a)^2$ then its derivative, $P'(x)=2(x-a)Q(x)+(x-a)^2 Q'(x)$. So, $P'(a)=0$. So if at least two roots occur at $a$ then its derivative it zero, so it is parallel to X-axis.

Comment: @PeaceSeeker In that case I can give you an intuition but not a proof: Consider the polynomial : $P(x)=Q(x)(x-a-b)(x-a)$ It has two roots: one at $a$ and another at $a+b$ Now keep on decreasing $b$ to 0. $P(a)=0$ and $P(a+b)=0$ Now visualise the corresponding graphs. Did you get it?